# Java projects dependencies tree in multimodule maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How could I build the tree (graph) of projects being used by current java project?
How could I build the tree (graph) of projects that use (depend on) current java project?
It is essential to build the tree, not a flat dependencies list.
And I don't want to have other maven dependencies in that tree to have clear project dependencies report.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use existing commands in eclipse as shown in the below picture:[image]

Open plugin.xml and you see several tabs like shown in pic : `Overview`, `Dependencies`.....

On the `Dependencies` tab, there is a `Dependency Analysis` section in which there are two commands that serves your purpose.

The `Show the plugin-dependency hierarchy` command list the plugins that your plugin depends on.

The `Show dependent plug-ins and fragments` command lists the plugins that depend on your plugin.

They are shown in a `tree` format.